# How to allow cross origin requests for all https domains

Tags: http, security, cors, http-headers

I serve my site with SSL and I want to accept cross-origin requests only from sites with SSL as well.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, but accepting all secure origins with credentials is _not_ what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The basic logic that you need is:

IF the value of the `Origin` request header STARTS WITH `https:`

THEN include a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header with the value copied from the `Origin` request header.

ELSE … don't.

---

The specifics of how you implement that pseudo-code will depend on what technology you are using on your server.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much, is it possible with nginx?

Comment: My nginx experience is nowhere near strong enough to say. This is the type of thing I'd generally implement at the server-side programming level rather than the HTTP server configuration level though.